# How to Find exact Match then Paste Similar Value to adjacent Cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a function which match the exact value in the raw string if macthes then paste the value but here Lookup function is giving an wrong answer.

I know how to extract it using Left function but how to macth exact string like in VBA we use Criteria: "*" & CellValue & "*".

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,SEARCH($K$3:$K$97,A3),$K$3:$K$97)
```

This function is not matching exact string as you can see in attached picture.

[image]

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19vNLnsWOgUZrnDsxFZbXipOWT_HqbRq587RqwDaSppg/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=IF(RegExMatch(B2,'Match Criteria'!B:B),"YES","NO")
```

Comment: Could you also include the expected output in your sample spreadsheet?

Comment: I have updated the output in the sheet.

Comment: think the 4th row in your sample data should be deleted, the output does not match the corresponding data of the same row. Also what are the criteria in searching the State and Zip code?

Comment: I have updated my question @Nikko J.

Comment: Apologies but I'm still confused on what is your process on getting the expected output. Could you confirm if this is what you want: 1. You want to check if the column B in `Data` Sheet contains state abbreviation and check if it exists in the `Match Criteria` Sheet and return the State abbreviation if true.

Comment: I apologise that i am unable to elaborate it well Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Paste this in cell **C3** of your Sample Spreadsheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B, "\b([A-Za-z]{2})\b(?:\s[\d{5}.]|$)"), REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B, "\b([A-Za-z]{4})\b(?:\s\d{5})")), 'Match Criteria'!B2:B, 1, FALSE)))
```

and for **D3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B3:B), "([\d]{5}\-[\d]{4}|[\d]{5})"),'Match Criteria'!A2:A,1,FALSE),))
```

Note: Make sure to change the format of Columns **A** & **B** of Sheet `Match Criteria` to **Plain Text**.

**Example output:**

[image]

### REFERENCES:

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en)
- [TO_TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285?hl=en)

Comment: Its working for States thank you very much. But when i applied this to Zipcode it wasn't working.@Nikko J.

Comment: Not it should not extract only 2letter string i have other states with 4 or different letters like `OHIO` formula should match the string from the Macth criteria and match it to the Data sheet if find then write to adjacent cell

Comment: @HSHO - To avoid back and forth, kindly finalize your sample spreadsheet by making a shorter version of it with all the possible combinations. I My answer is based on the sample spreadsheet you've provided and OHIO is not included during the time I copied your sample spreadsheet.  See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added the data accordinggly snd rempved the unneccsar data. and created one more solution but this is extremly slow @Nikko J.

Comment: There are still missing State Abbreviation in the Match Criteria Sheet that are present in Output section of your Data sheet. Example: GA, MI, NC etc.

Comment: I have updated the list

Comment: @HSHO - See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. There is still one confusion with zipcode i do not know why you can check here. https://ibb.co/r0835Qx

Comment: @HSHO - Have you formatted the column A & B of `Match Criteria` to Plain text? Highlight column A & B in Match Criteria Sheet -> Select Format Tab -> Number -> Plain text.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry to bother you. Its working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed this solution but it is extremly slow.

```
=OFFSET('Match Criteria'!$B$1,(SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(LEN(B3)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3," "&'Match Criteria'!$B$2:$B&" ","")))*(ROW('Match Criteria'!$B$2:$B)-1))),)
```